# Displayed data being doubled after inputing new data in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The inputed data of the user is getting doubled on the display like this:

Sample Display first Input: Sample 1
Display: Sample 1 second Input: Sample 2
Display: Sample 1, Sample 1, and Sample 2

I tried removing the fucntion displayEvents inside the onAuth but the same problem persists, here is the code below showing the fucntion displayEvents and the onAuth:

```
function displayEvents() {
  const eventList = document.getElementById("eventsList");

  const userRef2 = doc(db, "events", auth.currentUser.uid);
  const inputHistoryRef = collection(userRef2, "eventsList");

  
  const row = document.createElement("div");
  row.classList.add("row");

  const queryRef = query(inputHistoryRef);

  // Listen for real-time changes in the Firestore collection
  onSnapshot(queryRef, (querySnapshot) => {
    // Clear the existing event list before updating

    

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const eventData = doc.data();
          const eventId = doc.id;
          const col = document.createElement("div");
          col.classList.add("col-md-4"); // Adjust the column size as needed

          const card = document.createElement("div");
          card.classList.add("card");

          // Convert military time to standard time
          // const standardTime = convertToStandardTime(eventData.time);

          card.innerHTML = `
       
              <div class="card-body1" style="margin: 15px">
                  <h2 id="eventTitle" class="card-text " style="font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;">${eventData.title}</h2>
                  <p id="eventCategory" class="card-text"><strong>Category:</strong> ${eventData.category}</p>
                  <p id="eventLocation" class="card-text"><strong>Location:</strong> ${eventData.location}</p>
                  <p id="eventAdditionalInfo" class="card-text"><strong>Additional Information:</strong> ${eventData.additionalInformation}</p>
                  <p id="eventDate" class="card-text">
                  <strong>Date:</strong> 
                  <span class="badge bg-primary">${eventData.date}</span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="card-text">
                      <strong>Time:</strong> 
                      <span class="badge bg-info">${eventData.startTime} - ${eventData.endTime}</span>
                  </p>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="${eventId}">Delete</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="${eventId}">Archive</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editEventModal" id="${eventId}">Edit</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareEventModal" id="${eventId}">Share Event<i class="bx bx-mail-send nav_icon"></i></button>
              </div>
              
          `;

          col.appendChild(card);
          row.appendChild(col);

          eventList.appendChild(row);






          // Add event listeners for delete and edit buttons (implement the functionality)
          const deleteButton = card.querySelector(".btn-danger");
          const archiveButton = card.querySelector(".btn-warning");
          const editButton = card.querySelector(".btn-primary2");
          const shareButton = card.querySelector(".btn-success");

          

          deleteButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
              // Implement delete functionality here
              // You can use doc.id to identify the document to delete
              Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this event?',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                showDenyButton: true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                denyButtonText: `Delete`,
              }).then((result) => {
                /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                  if (result.isDenied) {
                  deleteEvent(eventId);
                  Swal.fire('Event Successfully Deleted', '', 'success')
                }
              })

          });
          archiveButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            // Implement delete functionality here
            // You can use doc.id to identify the document to delete
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Are you sure you want to archive this event?',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              showDenyButton: true,
              showCancelButton: true,
              denyButtonText: `Archive`,
            }).then((result) => {
              /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                if (result.isDenied) {
                archiveEvent(eventId);
                Swal.fire('Event Successfully Archived', '', 'success')
              }
            })

         });

          editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
              // Implement edit functionality here
              // You can use doc.id to identify the document to edit
               editEvent(eventId);
               

          });

          shareButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // Implement edit functionality here
            // You can use doc.id to identify the document to edit
             shareEvent(eventId);
             

          });
      });

      // Append the row to the event list
      
  });
}

onAuthStateChanged(auth, async function (user) {
  if (!user) {
    // User is not logged in, redirect to the login page
    auth.signOut()
      .then(() => {
        // Clear session storage
        sessionStorage.clear();
        // Redirect to the login page
        window.location.href = "../login.html";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors that occur during sign-out
        console.error('Error during sign-out:', error);
      });
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hidden-body").classList.remove("hidden");
    const loadingFrame = document.getElementById("loadingFrame");
    loadingFrame.parentNode.removeChild(loadingFrame);
    
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

    // console.log(userRef);

    getDoc(userRef)
    .then((docSnapshot) => {
      if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
        const userData = docSnapshot.data();
        const username = userData.username;
        const email = userData.email;
        console.log("Username:", username);

        document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = username;


      } else {
        console.log("User document not found");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error getting user document:", error);
    });
    
    const eventList = document.getElementById("eventsList");
    const userRef2 = doc(db, "events", auth.currentUser.uid);
    const inputHistoryRef = collection(userRef2, "eventsList");

    displayEvents();
    
    

  }
});
```